# Pandas two dataframes for loop: how to set value to old value + 1

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, for-loop

There are two dataframe **roads** and **bridges**.

If the kilometre point of a bridge falls between the chainage begin and end of a road segment, it should be checked which condition this bridge is in (this is A, B, C or D).

If the condition is **'A'** (this is a string) --> then in the roads df, the value under the column name **'BridgeA'** should become the **old value + 1**.

In the end, this column will show how many bridges of condition A a road segment contains.

The code we've written for this runs. However, it results in only zero's in the columns BridgeA, BridgeB, BridgeC and BridgeD.

Can someone help us out what is going wrong?

```
for j in roads.index: # loop through all the rows in the roads file

    for i in bridges.index: # for every line in the bridges file
        if bridges.km[i] > roads.Chainage_begin.loc[j] and \
        bridges.km[i] < roads.Chainage_end.loc[j]: # if the bridge falls within the road segment

            if bridges.condition[i] == 'A':
                roads.BridgeA.loc[j] =+ 1
            elif bridges.condition[i] == 'B':
                roads['BridgeB'].loc[j] =+ 1
            elif bridges.condition[i] == 'C':
                roads['BridgeC'].loc[j] =+ 1
            elif bridges.condition[i] == 'D':
                roads['BridgeD'].loc[j] =+ 1

        else: # if it is out of range
            continue # go on to the next row in the roads file
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never use `df.column[row_index]` nor `df[column][row_index]`. It works when you read a value but is error prone when you try to set a value. The only robust syntax is

```
df.loc[row_index, col] = ...
```

So here you should use:

```
        if bridges.condition[i] == 'A':
            roads.loc[j, 'BridgeA'] += 1
        elif bridges.condition[i] == 'B':
            roads.loc[j, 'BridgeB'] += 1
        elif bridges.condition[i] == 'C':
            roads.loc[j, 'BridgeC'] += 1
        elif bridges.condition[i] == 'D':
            roads.loc[j, 'BridgeD'] += 1
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! However, only when =+ is changed to += as well.

Comment: @FemkePragt My bad. I used `+=` in my tests and blindly copy your code to make sure to keep your names... Fixed.